# Change detection for nested objects in a state

Tags: ngxs

Let say we have a state with the following structure :

```
@State<StateModel>({
name: 'pg',
defaults: {
    docs: {
        doc1: { 
            id: 'doc1', 
            content: 'foo', 
        }
        doc2: { 
            id: 'doc2', 
            content: 'bar' 
        }
    }
}
```

How is change detection working ? If I do the change

```
@Action(UpdateContent)
update(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>) {
    ctx.patchState( { docs.doc2.content: 'something else' } );
}
```

None of the following observable emit a value :

```
obs1$ = store.select( state => state.docs );
obs2$ = store.select( state => state.docs.docs2 );
obs2$ = store.select( state => state.docs.docs2.content );
```

I am not an expert in rxjs programming but it seems strange, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try adding state name **pg** like this `obs1$ = store.select( state => state.pg.docs )` instead.
2. The state name is not required if you are selecting via `@Selector()`.
3. I assume your patchState() code's object notation is just an example.